# Proper way to handle scaling text with no javascript

Tags: html, css, media-queries, html-email

I am working on an email blast that I want to take up the full width of the clients email.  I have designed a responsive layout but I am running into a problem with font-size.  It seems there is no good way to tell the font to scale with the screen size, without using javascript.  Is my best solution to use media queries for a bunch of different screen sizes? I really would like the fluid sizing I get with javascript but because many email clients don't support JS in emails, especially web based viewers like gmail, it's not an option.  Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a default font-size declared (either by the browser or email client), the only way to make font-size scale is to use media-queries and change the font-size inside. It obviously won't work in clients that don't support them (which I'm sure you're aware of).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in html email. Even using media queries, there are slight variations in how text is rendered from client to client, so you would have issues with some text popping onto the next line.

Only alternative I would suggest is creating an image with your scalable text and set it at 100% width.